# WebSockets with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using websockets in my React application. The application is supposed to consist of function components only.

Imagine the application consists of two "tabs": one irrelevant, and the other one, a chat using websockets. Given that, we want to whip up a websocket connection once the user enters the chat tab.

How should the component handle the websocket object? Since we want to clean up once the user switches back to the other tab (`WebSocket.close()`), it sounds like we should be using an effect hook here.

```
const Chat = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://url");
        webSocket.onmessage = (message) => {
            setMessages(prev => [...prev, message.data]);
        };
        return () => webSocket.close();
    }, []);
    return <p>{messages.join(" ")}</p>;
};
```

Works! But now, imagine we want to reference the `webSocket` variable somewhere outside the `useEffect` scope - say, we want to send something to the server once the user clicks a button.

Now, how should it be implemented? My current idea (albeit a flawed one, I feel) is:

```
const Chat = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [webSocket] = useState(new WebSocket("ws://url"));
    useEffect(() => {
        webSocket.onmessage = (message) => {
            setMessages(prev => [...prev, message.data]);
        };
        return () => webSocket.close();
    }, []);
    return <p>{messages.join(" ")}</p>;
};
```

Kinda works, nevertheless I feel like there's a better solution.

Comment: Your question should be at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `useRef` to rescue. Also by now you're subscribing for new messages on each render. I believe it's enough to make that just once(`useEffect( ... , [])` or `useEffect( ..., [webSocketRef.current] )` in case it makes sense to recreate socket at some moment)

Answer (score 28):

As @skyboyer has written in a comment under your question, you could use `useRef` hook to hold `WebSocket` and it will be more correct since you are not going to change or recreate WebSocket object. So you don't need `useState` hook.

> The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class. [more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

So you could change your code to:

```
const Chat = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const webSocket = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        webSocket.current = new WebSocket("ws://url");
        webSocket.current.onmessage = (message) => {
            setMessages(prev => [...prev, message.data]);
        };
        return () => webSocket.current.close();
    }, []);
    return <p>{messages.join(" ")}</p>;
};
```

Comment: This is the solution I went for, however:
`useRef(new WebSocket("ws://url"));` constructs another WebSocket instance on every re-render. Things passed to useRef are evaluated every re-render, it's just that they're discarded if it's not the initial render.

My solution is to just `useRef(null)`, then construct it in the effect

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, you are right. I have updated my answer

Comment: Can you actually call `setMessages` with a callback like that? This would be very useful but there is nothing in the official documentation about this.

Comment: Nevermind! I found it. For ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Answer (score 9):

probably a good option is to have in a separate WS instance for manage the WS operations and used it where you need it, for example.

```
class WebSocketClient {
    static instance = null;
    callbacks = {};

    static getInstance() {
        if (!WebSocketClient.instance) WebSocketClient.instance = new WebSocketClient();
        return WebSocketClient.instance;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.socketRef = null;
    }

    addCallbacks = (...callbacks) => this.callbacks = { ...callbacks };

    connect = () => {
        const path = 'YOUR_SOCKET_PATH';
        this.socketRef = new WebSocket(path);
        this.socketRef.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket open');
        };

        this.socketRef.onmessage = e => {
            this.socketNewMessage(e.data);
        };

        this.socketRef.onerror = e => {
            console.log(e.message);
        };

        this.socketRef.onclose = () => {
            console.log("WebSocket closed let's reopen");
            this.connect();
        };
    }

    state = () => this.socketRef.readyState;

    waitForSocketConnection = (callback) => {
        const socket = this.socketRef;
        const recursion = this.waitForSocketConnection;
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                    console.log("Connection is made")
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback();
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log("wait for connection...")
                    recursion(callback);
                }
            },
        1);
    }

}

export default WebSocketClient.getInstance();
```

So in your component will be.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import WSC from 'wsc';


const Test = ({}) => {

    useEffect(()=>{
        WSC.connect();
        WSC.waitForSocketConnection(()=>{
            'HERE_YOUR_CALLBACKS'
        });
    },[])
}
```

With this way always return the same instance.

Comment: getting this error Uncaught TypeError: this.socketNewMessage is not a function
    at socketRef.onmessage