# Dev tools show many websocket requests of chat app built by react hook with functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, react-hooks

I have created a web chat client using websocket, react hook, react functional components and typescript.

My questions is that it generates new one request of websocket after a client, which is built by react functional component with hook, sending or receiving a message to the other client, which is same built by react hook with functional component. I observe this situation from network tab with filtering websocket 
 at browser dev tools. **What I wish is there is only one websocket connection during chat.**

But when I implement another client version using react class component type, this kind version only show one websocket during whole sending and receiving messages.

You can read the `App.tsx` code from [my github repository](https://github.com/yhunglee/chat-client/blob/master/src/App.tsx). Below are exerpt of `App.tsx` for  react-hook type's client:

```
export const App: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageType[]>([]);
  const testValue = { messages, setMessages };

  const ws = useRef(new WebSocket(URL));

  const renderCount = useRef(0);

  const submitMessage = (msg: MessageType) => {
    ws.current.send(JSON.stringify(msg));

    addMessage(msg);
  };

  const addMessage = (msg: MessageType) => {

    setMessages([...messages, msg]);

  };

  // websocket onmessage
  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current.onmessage = (msg) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(msg.data);
      message.isMe = false;

      addMessage(message);
    };

    console.log(`hello`);
  });

  // close websocket
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      ws.current.close();
    };
  }, [ws]);


  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App" css={appStyle}>
        <AppBar position="sticky">
          {console.log(`renderCount: ${(renderCount.current += 1)}`)}
          {/* debug */}
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6">聊天室</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <MessageHistory messages={messages} />
        <ChatInput submitFC={submitMessage} />
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
};
```

Below are screenshots of two local clients:
**Receiver:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Sender:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

The repository of other client version built by react class component is at [my github repository](https://github.com/yhunglee/example-chat-client).

Chat server's repository is at [my github another repository](https://github.com/yhunglee/example-chat-server)

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58433356/2704360) from other question at stackoverflow, but I don't know why. Version of react functional component with hook now can use only one websocket during a whole chat.

Below marked "// changed here" code are solution for `App.tsx`:

```
export const App: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageType[]>([]);
  const testValue = { messages, setMessages };

  // const ws = useRef(new WebSocket(URL));
  const ws = useRef<WebSocket | null>(null);  // changed here

  const renderCount = useRef(0);

  const submitMessage = (msg: MessageType) => {
    if (ws.current) {   // changed here
      ws.current.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }  // changed here

    addMessage(msg);
  };

  const addMessage = (msg: MessageType) => {

    setMessages((prev) => {   // changed here
      return [...prev, msg];  // changed here
    });                       // changed here
  };

  // websocket onmessage
  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket(URL);  // changed here
    ws.current.onmessage = (msg: MessageEvent) => { // changed here
      const message = JSON.parse(msg.data);
      message.isMe = false;

      addMessage(message);
    };
  }, []);                     // changed here

  // close websocket
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (ws.current) {       // changed here
        ws.current.close();
      }                       // changed here
    };
  }, [ws]);



  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App" css={appStyle}>
        <AppBar position="sticky">
          {console.log(`renderCount: ${(renderCount.current += 1)}`)}
          {/* debug */}
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6">聊天室</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <MessageHistory messages={messages} />
        <ChatInput submitFC={submitMessage} />
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
};
```

Below are screenshots.
[image]
[image]