# State variable hook not working with useEffect callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, state

Attempting to set up a websocket connection within a react functional component, and update a state variable with a hook, like so [Ref 1]:

```
export default function foo() {
    const [ arr, setArr ] = useState([])
    ws = useRef(null)

    useEffect( () => {
        ws.current = new Websocket('ws://example.com:1234')
        ws.current.onmessage = (m) => {
            setArr([...arr, m])
        })
    }, []) // Runs once at mount
}
```

The state of `arr` is not preserved. It is overwritten.

*NOTE* I also tried passing `arr` into the effect, like so, but this resulted in an endless loop. [Ref 2]. As arr was updated, the effect was called...

```
        })
    }, [arr])
}
```

For a more specific example, take three websocket messages:

```
['a']
['b']
['c']
```

Expected arr on each message, after update

```
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Result:

```
['a']
['b']
['c']
```

Why isn't `arr` stored with the `setArr` hook in the callback? Why is it an empty array?

**References**

1. [WebSockets with functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432076/websockets-with-functional-components)
2. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14066

Comment: Apologies I found this here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152922/proper-way-of-using-react-hooks-websockets/60161181#60161181

Answer (score 6):

You have

```
useEffect( () => {
    ws.current = new Websocket('ws://example.com:1234')
    ws.current.onmessage = (m) => {
        setArr([...arr, m])
    })
}, []) // Runs once at mount
```

Indeed, the effect hook there runs *once* on mount - and that's the problem. When it runs, the event listener that is attached, when triggered, runs this line:

```
setArr([...arr, m])
```

using the value of `arr` which is in scope for that handler. Since the handler is attached only once, on mount, the value of `arr` is always the same; the initial state, the empty array.

Use the callback instead:

```
setArr(arr => [...arr, m])
```

I'd also recommend declaring the `ws` with `const`, to avoid accidentally creating a global variable (and maybe call it `wsRef` rather than `ws`, so you don't confuse the ref for the socket):

```
const wsRef = useRef(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the previous state of your array instead as:

```
ws.current.onmessage = (m) => {
   setArr(prevState => [...prevState, m])
}
```

For `setState` there are two approaches how you can handle the change, the first is to give a **value as a parameter**, the second option is the pass a **callback function**. It's called updater function which provides the previous value of the state. Read further about `setState` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Where does ``prevState`` come from?

Comment: @kmiklas Just updated my solution to answer your question, I hope that clarifies.